# How to override InvalidSessionStrategy in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

The default implementation of InvalidSessionStrategy i.e. SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy in Spring security redirects the request to a default url. This default url comes from a final variable.

I would like to override the behavior by not redirecting all the time to the same url. How could I achieve that ? If I create a custom implementation of InvalidSessionStrategy, how can I use that ?

This is my configuration right now

```
and()
   .addFilterAfter(mySpringSecurityConfig.forceLogoutFilter(), PreAuthenticationFilter.class)
   .sessionManagement()
   .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
   .invalidSessionUrl("http://xxx/login.jsp")
   .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl(PropertyMgr.getCarnivalURL("http://xxx/login.jsp"))
```

But I don't want to use "http://xxx/login.jsp" for all invalid sessions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your entire configuration and the Spring Security version, so that we can have the whole picture.

However, to override `InvalidSessionStrategy`, simply define your class implementing this interface.
Then find a way to put your implementation into `SessionManagementFilter`.
One way can be via [SessionManagementConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html).

In the worst case you can always extend `SessionManagementFilter`, put your `InvalidSessionStrategy` there, and substitute the default sesssion filter.